# Programatically change font size in a linux terminal using python

Tags: terminal, gnome-terminal

In Ubuntu gnome-terminal it can be done by doing Ctrl + or Ctrl -
Is there a way to write a python script that when executed would resize the font size of the terminal it is executed from?

I need this in order to display images in terminal with high resolution using timg.

Answer (score 1):

Checking the source (vte and gnome-terminal), looks like there's no way to do this.  Other terminals (e.g., xterm) can do this using escape sequences.  See [*XTerm Control Sequences*](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#h2-Operating-System-Commands):

```
OSC Ps ; Pt ST
          Set Text Parameters.  For colors and font, if Pt is a "?", the
          control sequence elicits a response which consists of the con-
          trol sequence which would set the corresponding value.  The
          dtterm control sequences allow you to determine the icon name
          and window title.

  ...

            Ps = 5 0  -> Set Font to Pt.  These controls may be disabled
          using the allowFontOps resource.  If Pt begins with a "#",
          index in the font menu, relative (if the next character is a
          plus or minus sign) or absolute.  A number is expected but not
          required after the sign (the default is the current entry for
          relative, zero for absolute indexing).
```

vte recognizes the **`50`**, but that (like a lot of other xterm features) is just a stub that doesn't do anything.  The xterm sources include a [20-year old script](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.log.html#xterm_95) which demonstrates the feature (see [`fonts.sh`](https://github.com/ThomasDickey/xterm-snapshots/blob/master/vttests/fonts.sh)).

Rather than using an escape sequence, you might be able to use the [`wmctrl`](http://tripie.sweb.cz/utils/wmctrl/) tool (which could ask the *window manager* to negotiate with the terminal).  Some have done that with other terminals, e.g, [terminology](https://gist.github.com/raboof/11dab45e9f6300d7459e0d6cad435dd5) (but ultimately using an escape sequence).

vte **does** have some code which might be accessible from a python script, using `g_signal_connect` to associate  `decrease-font-size` and `increase-font-size` signal (see [source code](https://github.com/GNOME/vte/blob/master/src/app/app.cc#L1595)).  The [signal code](https://github.com/GNOME/vte/blob/master/src/vtegtk.cc#L1177) is what you're using with the keyboard.  But how you might determine the object pointer from a script starting outside the terminal emulator isn't clear.

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way to do this across terminals. Terminals support so called control sequences, which can set a bunch of options, like text color and others, but there is no control sequence for setting the font size. See for example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code and https://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html for what kind of actions are supported.